# Cannot Open Camera - OpenCV MacOS Python3

Tags: python, macos, opencv, camera

**Specs Detail**

- Macbook Pro 2020 13"
- MacOS Version : Bigsur 11.3.1
- OpenCV Version : 4.5.1
- Python Version : 3.9.4
- Camera : Default Facetime Camera
- Running on iTerm 2 Build 3.4.6

**Problems**

Camera isn't opened when launching this code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Screenshot**

[camera not opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4iAS.png)

[camera permission has been given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE8vv.png)

**Additional Info :**

I have two camera installed (one of them is epoccam, a camera drive for using smartphone as camera)

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. If you do not add a question to the answer, then it will not be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling EpocCam